# Possible to use fetch with the file:// protocol so as not to require a web server?

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch-api

I have a small local one-page site that's using the [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to grab some JSON data and parse it. It's all built using vanilla JavaScript and will be served locally only. I would like to make it work simply by opening the index.html file in a web browser without installing a local web server, but currently I am running into a CORS issue due to the `origin` being `null` since it's using the `file://` protocol. Is it possible to configure the `fetch` call to ignore CORS?

Example of the fetch call:

```
fetch('js/data.json')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(function (res) {
  console.log(res);
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Here is the error:

```
Access to fetch at 'file:///C:/Users/public/Desktop/site/js/data.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, isolated-app, brave, https, chrome-untrusted, data, chrome-extension, chrome.
```